# Crystal report and auto width of a number field

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, width

How I can make number field dinamically grow?
I have stored proc and one of the output column is number which can vary a lot in size.
How I can manage to set width to adjust and grow dinamically?

Comment: grow `vertically` or `horizontally`?

Comment: I don't think you have option to grow horizontally... you have a option to grow vertically using `Can Grow` but one thing I can suggest is to keep the size of the field to the maximum possible